# How to apply the style of the rest of the items when I click item in REACT?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, frontend, web-frontend

pic1

[image]

pic2

[image]

pic3

[image]

When I select one item, I want to apply the new style of one item and the original style of the rest of the items

Example

when I click SubBookmark33

Current

pic1 -> pic2

But I want to

pic1 -> pic3

BookmarksFolder.js

```
import BookmarksFolderNode from './BookmarksFolderNode';
import classes from './BookmarksFolder.module.css';

import { folders } from '../../resources/data';

function BookmarksFolder() {

  return (
    <div className={classes.bookmarksFolder}>
      {folders.map((folder) => (
        <BookmarksFolderNode
          key={folder.id}
          folder={folder}
        />
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}

export default BookmarksFolder;
```

BookmarksFolderNode.js

```
import { useState, useRef } from 'react';
import { AiFillCaretDown, AiFillCaretRight } from 'react-icons/ai';
import Folder from '../../resources/img/folder.svg';
import OpenedFolder from '../../resources/img/opened_folder.svg';

import classes from './BookmarksFolderNode.module.css';

function BookmarksFolderNode(props) {
  const [folderIsOpen, setFolderIsOpen] = useState(false);
  const tab = useRef();
  const img = useRef();
  const title = useRef();

  const selectFolderHandler = () => {
    tab.current.style.backgroundColor = '#1a73eb';
    img.current.src = OpenedFolder;
    title.current.style.color = '#1a73eb';
  };

  const openFolderHandler = () => {
    setFolderIsOpen((prevState) => !prevState);
  };

  const paddingLeft = 20 * (props.folder.depth - 1);

return (
    <div className={classes.bookmarksFolderNode}>
      <div className={classes.bookmarksMainFolderNode}>
        <div className={classes.verticalTab} ref={tab}></div>
        <div className={classes.innerContainer} style={{paddingLeft}}>
          <div className={classes.icon} onClick={openFolderHandler}>
            {folderIsOpen ? (
              <AiFillCaretDown className={classes.ironIcon} />
            ) : (
              <AiFillCaretRight className={classes.ironIcon} />
            )}
          </div>
          <img src={Folder} className={classes.folderIcon} ref={img} />
          <div
            className={classes.menuLabel}
            onClick={selectFolderHandler}
            ref={title}
          >
            {props.folder.title}
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div className={classes.bookmarksSubFolderNode}>
        {props.folder.subFolder &&
          props.folder.subFolder.map((subFolder) => (
            <BookmarksFolderNode key={subFolder.id} folder={subFolder} />
          ))}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default BookmarksFolderNode;
```

data.js

```
export const folders = [
  {
    id: 1,
    depth: 1,
    title: 'Bookmark 1',
    subFolder: [
      {
        id: 1,
        depth: 2,
        title: 'SubBookmark 1',
        subFolder: [
          {
            id: 1,
            depth: 3,
            title: 'SubBookmark 11',
          },
          {
            id: 2,
            depth: 3,
            title: 'SubBookmark 22',
          },
          {
            id: 3,
            depth: 3,
            title: 'SubBookmark 33',
            subFolder: [
              {
                id: 1,
                depth: 4,
                title: 'SubBookmark 111',
              },
            ],
          },
        ],
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        depth: 2,
        title: 'SubBookmark 2',
      },
    ],
  },
];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The idea is that, when you select a folder, you should deselect the others from parent component `BookmarksFolder`. The solution is a little bit tricky because you select the folder using `BookmarksFolderNode` local state (I mean `folderIsOpen`).

Well, lets start to use parent component's state to select/deselect folder:

```
import BookmarksFolderNode from './BookmarksFolderNode';
import classes from './BookmarksFolder.module.css';

import { folders } from '../../resources/data';

function BookmarksFolder() {
  const [foldersSelected, setFoldersSelected] = useState(new Array(folders.length).fill(false));

  const selectFolder = (index) => {
     let result = new Array(folders.length).fill(false);
     result[index] = true;
     setFoldersSelected(result);
  }

  return (
    <div className={classes.bookmarksFolder}>
      {folders.map((folder, index) => (
        <BookmarksFolderNode
          key={folder.id}
          folder={folder}
          isSelected={foldersSelected[index]}
          select={(index) => selectFolder(index)}
          index={index}
        />
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}

export default BookmarksFolder;
```

So now in `BookmarksFolderNode` we have to use `isSelected` and `select` instead of `folderIsOpen` and `openFolderHandler`. Not only but we have to replicate the same logic for subfolders:

```
import { useState, useRef, useEffect } from 'react';
import { AiFillCaretDown, AiFillCaretRight } from 'react-icons/ai';
import Folder from '../../resources/img/folder.svg';
import OpenedFolder from '../../resources/img/opened_folder.svg';

import classes from './BookmarksFolderNode.module.css';

function BookmarksFolderNode(props) {
  const [subfoldersSelected, setSubFoldersSelected] = useState(new Array(props.folder.subFolder.length).fill(false));
  const tab = useRef();
  const img = useRef();
  const title = useRef();

  useEffect(() => {
     if (props.isSelected) {
        tab.current.style.backgroundColor = '#1a73eb';
        img.current.src = OpenedFolder;
        title.current.style.color = '#1a73eb';
     }
     else {
        tab.current.style.backgroundColor = 'black';
        img.current.src = Folder;
        title.current.style.color = 'black';
     }
  }, [props.isSelected])

  const openFolderHandler = () => {
    props.select(props.index)
  };

  const paddingLeft = 20 * (props.folder.depth - 1);

  const selectSubfolder = (index) => {
     let result = new Array(props.folder.subFolder.length).fill(false);
     result[index] = true;
     setSubFoldersSelected(result);
  }

return (
    <div className={classes.bookmarksFolderNode}>
      <div className={classes.bookmarksMainFolderNode}>
        <div className={classes.verticalTab} ref={tab}></div>
        <div className={classes.innerContainer} style={{paddingLeft}}>
          <div className={classes.icon} onClick={openFolderHandler}>
            {props.isSelected ? (
              <AiFillCaretDown className={classes.ironIcon} />
            ) : (
              <AiFillCaretRight className={classes.ironIcon} />
            )}
          </div>
          <img src={Folder} className={classes.folderIcon} ref={img} />
          <div
            className={classes.menuLabel}
            onClick={openFolderHandler}
            ref={title}
          >
            {props.folder.title}
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div className={classes.bookmarksSubFolderNode}>
        {props.folder.subFolder &&
          props.folder.subFolder.map((subFolder, index) => (
            <BookmarksFolderNode key={subFolder.id} folder={subFolder} index={index} isSelected={subfoldersSelected[index]} select={(index) => selectSubfolder(index)} />
          ))}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default BookmarksFolderNode;
```

So now, if you select a folder (or a subfolder) the others folder (or subfolders) will be deselected and the `useEffect` will apply the desidered css.

Comment: TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined 
BookmarksFolderNode
C:/Users/xorua/project/log/src/components/bookmarks/BookmarksFolderNode.js:12

Comment: const [subfoldersSelected, setSubFoldersSelected] = useState(new Array(props.folder.length).fill(false)); change props.folder.subFolder to props.folder

Comment: It can only be in the same location, not in a different location.

Comment: @Lee yes this is the limitation. But you could solve easly: When a folder is selected, deselect all the other folder and subfolders.

Comment: @Lee If you really need more help to solve (I don't think so but could be), please make a codesandbox or some with your actual code and I will check what it doesn't work. Anyway we are close to solve it =). Let me know, Ciao

Comment: The Current idea is to add one value in the array(selected) and to manage the  four states(prevIndex, prevDepth, currentIndex,
currentDepth) with Redux

Comment: The selected item changes the selected value to true, Put the index and depth of the item in current. Then search the index and depth of the previously selected item in prev, Change the selected value to false and Re-render

Comment: How do these method look? and Is Inefficient?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem seems to be that you are just editing the currently clicked node. What do you need to do is in "selectFolderHandler" to reset the image of all other items.

One approach would be to iterate through each item, and set the image to initial, and then change the currently selected (not wise because of performance).

A suggested approach would be to find an open folder image (if it exists) and reset it. The simplest is to search by class or ref attribute.

Comment: Is there a way to access each item without iterating each item

Comment: You should do it with [use memo](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usememo) and [use callback](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecallback). for finding a specific item. I would suggest adding an extra class (i.e. opened). Using this approach, you would have direct access to the item you need to reset to the initial state.